# Openshift Upgrade Plan From India

Tags: openshift, openshift-cartridge

I have an application on free tier in openshift , which is working excellent .I just want upgrade my plan to sliver. but my country india is not shown while upgrading. Is there anyway to upgrade my plan from india. Thanks a million to the folks who tries to help me.

Comment: HI even i am  the user from India of the openshift account and do not have the facility for upgrade account.

Comment: One way is any friend/relative of yours in any of the countries listed can help you in the upgradation not sure why the Openshift Team is not accepting the cards from India..requested the Openshift Team for the upgrade account facility in the link "do not see your country" and added the request there.